# Can't enter BIOS after installing Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu loads so fast

Tags: boot, bios

When I press F2 key to open BIOS, it says "Please wait..." in the bottom of the screen, which used to be followed by the BIOS screen before I installed Ubuntu. But now, the screen turns black and then Ubuntu appears without going into BIOS. I can't enter the BIOS.

I've tried using `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup`, but I've got `firmware doesn't support boot into firmware` error.

I've also tried increasing `GRUB_TIMEOUT` in /etc/default/grub but it didn't help either.

Finally, I've also tried powering off my machine, removing the battery (it's a laptop), holding the power button for 20 seconds and turning on again, but that didn't change anything. I don't remember enabling Fast Boot in BIOS anyway.

My laptop is Samsung NP300E5C-S06DE. I had Windows 10 before I installed Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @David I don't think this is something related to hardware. Or at least it isn't a problem, because this issue didn't exist until I installed Ubuntu.

Comment: @David That's not true. I've seen Ubuntu installs cause failure to enter the BIOS. It's not a hardware problem.

Comment: @YılmazAlpaslan Does BIOS/firmware appear as an item in your GRUB menu? Do you still have Windows installed?

Comment: @heynnema All comments removed and will not comment on any other post. Happy?

Comment: @David No insult intended. It was just that your information was not correct. Please continue to contribute where you see fit.

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: try `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` in grub, and don't forget to run `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 2):

Bios loading occurs and only then system boot.
The operating system has nothing to do with it.
According to the description, it looks like the fast boot setting is enabled.

Try hold down the F2 key, then power on.
That should get you into the BIOS setup Utility.

You can disable the Fast Boot Option here.  Disable Fast Boot if you want to use Boot menu.